# If $\phi(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \phi(\lambda_n) P_n+\phi(0)P_0$ converges to $\phi(T)$ in Operator norm.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_n P_n$ , be a compact, normal operator on a Hilbert space $H$ and let $P_0$ denote the orthogonal projection of $H$ onto $Ker(T)$ ,where $\lambda_n$ are the non-zero eigenvalues of $T$ and $P_n$ are orthogonal projections onto $Ker(T-\lambda_n I)$. Let $\phi$ be a bounded function on $\Bbb C$, $\phi(T)(h)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \phi(\lambda_n) P_n(h)+\phi(0)P_0(h)$ $\forall h \in H$

> Prove that, if $\phi(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \phi(\lambda_n) P_n+\phi(0)P_0$ converges to $\phi(T)$ in Operator norm.

My attempt:

Let, $K=\oplus_{n=1}^l Ker(T-\lambda_n I)$

Then, $\phi(T) - \sum_{n=1}^l \phi(\lambda_n) P_n = 0 $ on $K$ and  $T$ on $K^{\perp}$

Thus, $||\phi(T) - \sum_{n=1}^l \phi(\lambda_n) P_n||_{Op}$=$max\{||(\phi(T) - \sum_{n=1}^l \phi(\lambda_n) P_n)|_{K}||,||(\phi(T) - \sum_{n=1}^l \phi(\lambda_n) P_n)|_{K^{\perp}}||\}$

= $||\sum_{n=l+1}^\infty \phi(\lambda_n) P_n||$ = $\sup_{n \ge l+1} |\phi(\lambda_n)| \to 0 $ as $l \to \infty$ .

Thus the convergence is Op norm.

Please point out mistakes if any. Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1):

[I'm posting my comment as an answer in case you're ready to close the question.]

Aside from correcting the index on the first line of your attempt to $n$
and changing the last line to $l \rightarrow \infty$ instead of $n \rightarrow 0$, it looks good to me. It could be worth explicitly mentioning that the supremum converges to 0 because $\lambda_n \rightarrow 0$ (by compactness of $T$), but it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: Can you kindly explain the last statement in a bit more detail, what you're trying to suggest.

Comment: For a sequence $(\alpha_n)$, the statement $\sup_{n \ge l} |\alpha_n| \rightarrow 0$ as $l \rightarrow \infty$ is equivalent to $\alpha_n \rightarrow 0$, so the last line of your proof is essentially saying that $\phi(\lambda_n) \rightarrow 0$.  We only know that $\phi(\lambda_n) \rightarrow 0$ because $\phi(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ and because $\lambda_n \rightarrow 0$.  And we know the latter because the eigenvalues of any compact operator (if they can be written as an infinite sequence) must converge to 0, b/c 0 is the only accumulation point in the spectrum of a compact $T$.